# ListView In TabBarView In Container not scrolling dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following flutter/dart code where the listView which is inside a tabBarView and also inside a container isn't scrollable

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: [
    ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // new
        controller: _controllerView,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: CustomText(
              text: "User Details",
              size: 20,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: darkPrimary,
            ),
          ),
        
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.date_range_rounded),
            title: CustomText(
              text: "Joined",
              color: grey,
              size: 15,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            subtitle: CustomText(
              text: "Jan 2020",
              size: 18,
              color: darkPrimary,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            dense: true,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded),
            title: CustomText(
              text: "Active",
              color: grey,
              size: 15,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            subtitle: CustomText(
              text: "3 days ago",
              size: 18,
              color: darkPrimary,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            dense: true,
          ),
          
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: CustomText(
              text: "Description",
              size: 20,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: darkPrimary,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: CustomText(
              text:
                  "khfkjsh dkjash dkjash kdhask dhkas dkashkd askd asdh aksjhdkasj dkhhas dk askdh ask dhas hdas dh ask daskhh daskj daks dka  asdh as dasjh",
              size: 15,
              weight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: grey[700],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
    ListView(children: [])
  ]),
)
```

This is the controller code

```
TabController _controller;
ScrollController _controllerView = new ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }
```

Is there any problem with this code that is making it not scrollable instead the screen looks as if it is fixed. please help me out am a beginner in flutter/dart

**Update: Instead I used Litview on like this and changed the other to column. even though its not what i want its still ok**

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try to wrap the ListView in Expanded or Stack
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your container with

```
SingleChildScrollView
```

Comment: @Brightcode Can you provide a fix height/width (depends on where you want to scroll) to your container?!

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap the `ListView` in `Expanded`